# Hide parent TR if link has no href?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I current have this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Website</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <a href="">Visit Website</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Website</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <a href="">Visit Website</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need some javascript that will:
if `<a>` has no href (href="") then hide the TR that wraps it.

How do I achieve this using javascript?

Comment: Just to be pedantic, technically you can't say that `<a href="">` "has no href".

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** for getting `a` tag with `href=""` and then get `tr` by **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

```js
$('a[href=""]').closest('tr').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Website</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <a href="">Visit Website</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Website</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <a href="">Visit Website</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Or you can use **[`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)** or **[`has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/)** and **[attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**.

```js
$('tr:has(a[href=""])').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Website</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="">Visit Website</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Website</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="">Visit Website</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**FYI :**

If you want to select `a` tag without `href` attribute then you can use **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** selector, eg:

```
$('a[href=""],a:not(a[href])').closest('tr').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

#### If you want to check for only href=""

simply try

```
$('a[href=""]').parent().parent().hide();
```

or

```
$('a[href=""]').closest("tr").hide();
```

#### If you also want to check for only href="" or no href attribute given

simply try

```
$('a[href=""],a:not([href])').parent().parent().hide();
```

or

```
$('a[href=""],a:not([href])').closest("tr").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/ Have a look at this now its working please check